# What reduces my view distance deep down?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

While cruising the bottom of a deep ravine, I found places where my view distance gets reduced in a manner similar to the Void Fog. Thing is, the bottom of the ravine is flat where that occurs. I just walk, seeing the walls lit with dozens of torches on multiple levels, and then as I enter certain area, my view gets shorter, distant torches dim, then it all gets cut off, I see only like thirty blocks ahead, the rest swallowed by darkness. Then a little way further the vision gradually returns to normal. There are two such places in that ravine and I didn't find anything like that elsewhere.

This is fairly deep and I wouldn't be surprised to be affected by the Void Fog, but if I understand, the intensity of the Fog is directly proportional to your depth past certain threshold - and this seems as if I were entering some... hill of the fog? Also, there are no floating particles like in the deepest layers.

So, what can cause that local reduction of view distance?

Comment: Does this ravine have any skylights? Void fog is "banished" in a certain radius from where sun/moon light reaches.

Comment: Is this vanilla minecraft, or are you running any mods?

Comment: @Saint: Yes, vanilla.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: Yes, there are some "skylights" (or actually TNT drop shafts) and that just might be it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds like plain-old void fog, which is removed by exposure to the zenith. It gradually returns further away, similar to the light pattern around a torch.